# Crawler got identified when headers provided and requst interval set

Tags: python, request, web-crawler, steam

Steam provides an endpoint which shows market information of a specific item. Parameter includes country, currency, language, item_nameid, and two_factor.

For example,
*https://steamcommunity.com/market/itemordershistogram?country=TW&language=english&currency=30&item_nameid=176185978&two_factor=0*

means my country, currency, and language are TW, 30(TWD), and english. ID of the item I'm interesting in is 17618597.

Normally, you can continually access this endpoint without any problem after loggin. I tried accessing this endpoint thirty times within one minute, no problem occurred.

But when using requests library to access this endpoint, steam quickly identified crawling even when user-agent, cookies, other headers provided and requst interval set. I got ip banned after 8 to 12 requests.

My code:

```
url = 'https://steamcommunity.com/market/itemordershistogram'
payload = {'country': 'TW', 'language': 'english', 'currency': 30, 'item_nameid': 176185978, 'two_factor': 0}

# headers copied from network tab
temp = '''Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: zh-TW,zh;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Host: steamcommunity.com
Pragma: no-cache
sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="107", "Chromium";v="107", "Not=A?Brand";v="24"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'''

headers = {key: value for key, value in [line.split(': ') for line in temp.split('\n')]}    // conver headers from string literals to dict

temp = 'cookies copied from network tab'
cookies = {key: value for key, value in [pair.split('=') for pair in temp.split('; ')]}    // conver cookies from string literals to dict

session = Session()

for i in range(100):
    print(f'{i}:')
    res = session.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload, cookies=cookies)
    print(res.status_code)
    print(res.text)

    sleep_time = 5 + random.random()
    time.sleep(sleep_time)
```

I do some research on how to deal with anti-spider, most article saying setting user-agent, cookies or extending request interval would help. But in my case, steam still be able to identified crawling.

Some article says adding Referer header would help, but I see no Referer header in browser's network tab.
Therefore, I assume adding Referer header wouldn't help.

So I'm wondering, besides user-agent, cookies, other headers and the request interval, how can steam know I'm using a crawler?

Comment: Solved by adding referer header, still don't understand why chrome can send request without referer header and not being anti-crawled.